# How to make queries to remote Postgres in different views in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm making a project where I need to access to remote databases and get data from it.

I'm connecting to remote postgres database and getting list of all tables in my class-based view like so:

```
    try:
        # connect to the PostgreSQL serve
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host='host',
            database='db_name',
            user='username',
            password='password',
            port='port',
        )

        # create a cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        cursor.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
```

Now, in another view I want to make other queries (like retrieving specific rows from specific table). How am I able to do that?

The goal is to take all credentials from user's input in template to connect to db. Then on another template choose which table and which rows to use to get certain data.

Comment: Is there any reason to use direct pyscopg connection instead of django database official support? see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: _The goal is to take all credentials from user's input in template to connect to db. Then on another template choose which table and which rows to use to get certain data._ . Assuming a stateless django app, you need to persist the user's input credentials somewhere to reuse these credentials (like session) in another view. Or post it every time (using input hidden). Sessions docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/
. I don't recommend store any credentials, but you are free to do this assuming the risks.

Comment: @iuridiniz Yes, there's a reason as I need to make a feature to connect to any database of any type (PostgreSQL, MySQL etc.) from my app and use the data to show analytics. If you see geckoboard.com, you can choose there, for example, to connect to social networks, to API, or to database. When you choose database, you input credentials and get access to your db.

Comment: I've done a migration app (migrate data between databases). I've a form where the user saves the credentials in the database (using a model) and reuse them to proceed the migration. In this project, I've been using sqlalchemy since it provides easy usage and it has a powerful  introspect api (discovery tables, columns and etc). Is this useful to you? Docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#

Comment: Another idea, if you have enough knowledge in javascript and websockets, it's make a websocket connection (which will make you app have stateful connection) and use it. Django-channels is a good start point: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html

Comment: by looking geekboard, if you want something close to it, I recommend use a backend server to collect data in background and post it to somewhere where you could retrieve (producer X consumer approach). In my XP, I would do: backend app (producer) -> rabbitmq // javascript app -> websocket (consumer) -> rabbitmq. You must store credentials in you django db and retrieve this credentials from the backend app

Comment: (continuing...) Also, I recommend usage of a time series database to store the stats. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database

Comment: @iuridiniz so many options) Thanks for your help! Will try to do any of these. As for now, django sessions work for me